# Javascript show/hide not working when the select box above is used before it

Tags: javascript, php, select

Im using this code below with a select box to show and hide divs, the page has multiple select boxes which all use the show hide javascript.

If I just use one of the drop down select boxes it shows and hide fine but if you change the one above it first, it unhides the selected but does not hide the last selected div.

If you change it a few more times (i guess on and off the div that didnt hide the first time) it corrects itself.

Can anyone see anything obvious or is there a way to ensure the code is not retaining something from the previous selection?

***Javascript***

```
     var lastselectedDiv = "";

    function showselectedDiv(divName) {

        newStr = divName.substr(2);
        newlastselectedStr = lastselectedDiv.substr(2);


        if (lastselectedDiv) {
                if  (newStr == newlastselectedStr) {            
            document.getElementById(lastselectedDiv).className = "hideDiv";
                } else {
            document.getElementById(lastselectedDiv).className = "showDiv";         
                }
        }

        if (divName && document.getElementById(divName)) {
            document.getElementById(divName).className = "showDiv";
            divqty = '2|' + newStr;

            if (divName == divqty) { } else {
            document.getElementById(divqty).className = "hideDiv";
            }
            lastselectedDiv = divName;
        }
    }
```

```
<?php

        <?php echo'<div id="1|' .$product->get_sku() . '" class="hideDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item.</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Save ££ when buying more than one </div>           
    </div>
    <?php echo'<div id="2|' .$product->get_sku(). '" class="showDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy2($multibuyprice);?><div style="margin-top:10px;float:right;width: 78%;color:black;font:16px arial;text-decoration:line-through;"><?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?></div>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Includes multibuy discount for 2<br> Save more when you buy more</div>
    </div>
    <?php echo'<div id="3|' .$product->get_sku(). '" class="hideDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy3($multibuyprice);?><div style="margin-top:10px;float:right;width: 78%;color:black;font:16px arial;text-decoration:line-through;"><?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?></div>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Includes multibuy  discount for 3<br>Save more when you buy more </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo'<div id="4|' .$product->get_sku(). '" class="hideDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy4($multibuyprice);?><div style="margin-top:10px;float:right;width: 78%;color:black;font:16px arial;text-decoration:line-through;"><?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?></div>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Includes multibuy  discount for 4<br>Save more when you buy more </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo'<div id="5|' .$product->get_sku(). '" class="hideDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy5($multibuyprice);?><div style="margin-top:10px;float:right;width: 78%;color:black;font:16px arial;text-decoration:line-through;"><?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?></div>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Includes multibuy discount for 5<br></div>
    </div>
    <?php echo'<div id="6|' .$product->get_sku(). '" class="hideDiv" > '?>
    <?php multibuy6($multibuyprice);?><div style="margin-top:10px;float:right;width: 78%;color:black;font:16px arial;text-decoration:line-through;"><?php multibuy1($multibuyprice);?></div>
    <div id="priceperitem">Price per item</div>
    <div id="savewhenbuying">Includes multibuy discount for 6</div>
    </div>


    <?php echo '</div>'?>   
    <?php echo '<div id=labelright>'?>

                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'season_type', true); ?>
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'flat', true); ?>

<?php echo '</div></div>'?>



<?php echo '<div id=labelsizeouter>'?>
<?php echo '<div id=buttonholder>'?>

     <?php echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <select id="amountofitems" onchange="showselectedDiv(this.value);" class="input-
 text qty text" name="quantity";>
<option value="1|' .$product->get_sku(). '">1</option>
<option value="2|' .$product->get_sku(). '"selected>2</option>
<option value="3|' .$product->get_sku(). '">3</option>
<option value="4|' .$product->get_sku(). '">4</option>
 <option value="5|' .$product->get_sku(). '">5 </option>
<option value="6|' .$product->get_sku(). '">6</option>
<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="'?><?php the_ID(); ?><?php 
echo '"><button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button 
alt">Buy items >></button></form>'?><?php echo '</div>'?>
```

Comment: Can you add the php code to your post?

Comment: Why is this tagget with Java?

Comment: can you give us a complete example including your html?

Comment: Using of inline css styles is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating values for the `id` attributes in your HTML:
`<div id="priceperitem">` and `<div id="savewhenbuying">`

That's probably the issue. It doesn't matter that each of the divs having a duplicate `id` is the child element of a distinctly named parent `div` -  they must still be unique themselves.

All `id` values should be distinct. If you want to do something to a collection of elements consider adding a `class` attribute to those elements.

[From w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).
>
> The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet,
>   and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with
>   the specific id.

Comment: I have changed that and it still does it, it like its getting corrupted by the previous use if thats even possible,  is there a way to refresh, clear it or flush it onchange? so its back to the state it was when the page loaded? ie. onchange flush first then showselectedDiv(this.value);

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found why its not working properly, basically it stores a global variable as "var lastselectedDiv" but if the last selected item was from a different drop down select then it will think the last selected was something different from the current selected div and not hide it.

Based on the code I already have how would send the current selected with the new selected div? for example at the moment I have "onchange="showselectedDiv(this.value);" can I have onchange="showselectedDiv(this.value) and lastselectedDiv(this.value);" lastselectedDiv would send the current selected i was going from to function where the newlastselectedStr = lastselectedDiv.substr(2);

Answer (score 0):

It was remembering last "var lastselectedDiv" from the last changed select which would work fine if you on had one but I could have more than 20 on one page.

I fixed it by changing all show/hides divs instead of just changing the selected one and the "var lastselectedDiv" which was meant to be the last shown div

New Javascript piece of code:

```
function showselectedDiv(divName) {

               newStr = divName.substr(2);
               sendselect1 = '1|' + newStr;
               sendselect2 = '2|' + newStr;
               sendselect3 = '3|' + newStr;
               sendselect4 = '4|' + newStr;
               sendselect5 = '5|' + newStr;
               sendselect6 = '6|' + newStr;

if  (divName == sendselect1) { 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "showDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "hideDiv";

  } else if (divName == sendselect2) { 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "showDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "hideDiv";

  } else if (divName == sendselect3) { 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "hideDiv"; 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "showDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "hideDiv";

  } else if (divName == sendselect4) { 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "hideDiv"; 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "showDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "hideDiv";

  } else if (divName == sendselect5) { 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "hideDiv"; 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "showDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "hideDiv";

  } else if (divName == sendselect6) {
                    document.getElementById(sendselect1).className = "hideDiv"; 
                    document.getElementById(sendselect2).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect3).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect4).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect5).className = "hideDiv";
                    document.getElementById(sendselect6).className = "showDiv";
}
}
```